# time complexity difference and how

Tags: c++, vector

`vector<int>& v` time complexity is lesser when executed compared with `vector<int> v`. Why?

```
int numUniqueEmails(vector<string>& emails) {

}
```

Without `&` it is 36ms.
With `&` it is 32ms.

Comment: If you don’t pass a reference then the whole vector must be copied.

Comment: I suggest reading Item 20 in Scott Meyer's Effective C++ ("Prefer pass-by-reference-toconst to pass-by-value").

Comment: Have you measured time using `&&` too?

Comment: Time complexity is not measured in seconds but as a function of the "size" of a problem. (With `&`, passing the parameter takes constant time; without `&`, it takes time linear in the number of elements.)

Comment: "*x* ms" is not called "time complexity." It is just "time."

Answer (score 0):

Below code is calling the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) of vector to all data is copied to another vector so it will take some time

```
 int numUniqueEmails(vector<string> emails) {

 }
```

If you add the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) `vector<string>& emails` then the original vector is referred here and no copy is created which saves time.